# convert mysql query to sql server query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to convert below mysql query to sql query.I want to use If condition in sql server

```
SELECT
foodName,
IF( foodPrice>2000, 'Expensive', 'Cheap') as fpDesc,
discountPercent
FROM restaurant.foods;
```

Comment: u could use of `IIF()` if u r working with `sql-server 2012` or `+` else `case` expression

Answer (score 4):

`if` is MySQL proprietary, as you noticed. The standard way to do this is `case`

```
CASE WHEN foodPrice > 2000
     THEN 'Expensive'
     ELSE 'Cheap'
 END
```

See also: http://modern-sql.com/feature/case